# Getting attributed html element

Tags: ruby, css-selectors, nokogiri

I'm trying to get table with content of MMEL codes from [this site](http://www.s-techent.com/ATA100.htm) and I'm trying to accomplish it with CSS Selectors.

What I've got so far is:

```
require_relative 'sources/Downloader'
require 'nokogiri'

html_content = Downloader.download_page('http://www.s-techent.com/ATA100.htm')
parsed_html = Nokogiri::HTML(html_content)

tmp = parsed_html.css("tr[*]")

puts tmp.text
```

And I'm getting error while trying to get this `tr` with attribute. How can I complete this task to get this table in simple form because I want to parse it to JSON. It would be nice go get this in sections and call it in`.each` block.

---

**EDIT:**
I'd be nic if I can get things in block like this (look into pages source)

```
<TR><TD WIDTH="10%" VALIGN="TOP" ROWSPAN=5>
<B><FONT FACE="Arial" SIZE=2><P ALIGN="CENTER">11</B></FONT></TD>
<TD WIDTH="40%" VALIGN="TOP"  COLSPAN=2>
<B><FONT FACE="Arial" SIZE=2><P>PLACARDS AND MARKINGS</B></FONT></TD>
<TD WIDTH="50%" VALIGN="TOP">
<FONT FACE="Arial" SIZE=2><P ALIGN="LEFT">All procurable placards, labels, etc., shall be included in the illustrated Parts Catalog.  They shall be illustrated, showing the part number, Legend and Location.  The Maintenance Manual shall provide the approximate Location (i.e., FWD -UPPER -RH) and illustrate each placard, label, marking, self -illuminating sign, etc., required for safety information, maintenance significant information or by government regulations.  Those required by government regulations shall be so identified.</FONT></TD>
</TR>
```

Comment: you want the full table information?

Comment: I've put in EDIT what I want :)

Comment: Do you want the table html? or any specific contents? I still not get your need. :)

Comment: Table HTML would be sufficient :)

Comment: So all `TR` you want right? :) final confirmation.

Comment: No :D I don't want all `TR`'s but I want only those from line 96 (source)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should print all those TR's from source at line 96.  There are three tables in that page and `table[1]` has all the text you needed:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.s-techent.com/ATA100.htm'))
doc.css("table")[1].css("tr").each do |i|
  puts i #=> prints the exact html between TR tags (including)
  puts i.text #=> prints the text
end
```

For instance:

```
puts doc.css("table")[1].css("tr")[2]
```

prints the following:

```
<tr>
<td valign="TOP" colspan="3">
<b><font face="Arial" size="2"><p align="CENTER">GROUP DEFINITION - AIRCRAFT</p></font></b>
</td>
<td valign="TOP">
<font face="Arial" size="2"><p align="LEFT">The complete operational unit.  Includes dimensions and
areas, lifting and shoring,    leveling and weighing, towing and taxiing, parking and mooring, requi
red placards, servicing.</p></font>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for :D I'm new to all this and forgot to chech how many tables are in this page...

Comment: @Cojoj You told you want from line 96 onwards.. :) so you want from the first table only?

Comment: I only wanted this table and I was hoping to help you with telling you that what I want starts at 96 :P

Comment: @Cojoj That's the reason I got late to answer! :) still i will post my one. No worry i am almost done!

Comment: Hah, you could also help me with creating JSON from every `TR` :P

Comment: @Cojoj That's my out of domain... :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do the same using `xpath` also:

Below is the content from the first table of the webpage given in the post by OP:

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri.HTML(open('http://www.s-techent.com/ATA100.htm'))
doc.xpath('(//table)[1]/tr').each do |tr|
  puts tr.to_html(:encoding => 'utf-8')
end
```

Output:

```html
  <tr>
  <td width="33%" valign="MIDDLE" colspan="2">
  <p><img src="S-Tech-Logo-Blue2.gif" width="274" height="127"></p>
  </td>
  <td width="67%" valign="MIDDLE">
  <b><i><font face="Arial" color="#0000ff">
  <p align="CENTER"><big>AIRCRAFT PARTS MANUFACTURING ASSISTANCE (PMA)</big><br><big>DAR SERVICES</big></p></font></i></b>
  </td>
  </tr>
```

Now, if you want to collect the last table rows, then do:

```ruby
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri.HTML(open('http://www.s-techent.com/ATA100.htm'))
p doc.xpath('(//table)[3]/tr').to_a.size # => 1
doc.xpath('(//table)[3]/tr').each do |tr|
  puts tr.to_html(:encoding => 'utf-8')
end
```

Output:

```html
<tr>
<td width="40%" valign="TOP" height="10">
<p align="CENTER"><b><font face="Arial" size="2" color="#0000ff">149 AZALEA CIRCLE • LIMERICK, PA 19468-1330</font></b></p>
</td>
<td width="30%" valign="TOP" height="10">
<p align="CENTER"><b><font face="Arial" size="2" color="#0000ff">610-495-6898 (Office) • 484-680-0507 (Cell)</font></b></p>
</td>
<td width="110%" valign="TOP" height="10">
<p align="CENTER"><a href="Contact.htm"><b><font face="Arial" size="2">E-mail S-Tech</font></b></a></p>
</td>
</tr>
```